# Spring Sleuth does not populate traceid and spanid to RabbitHandler

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-sleuth

We want to use spring sleuth together with spring-amqp (rabbitmq). 
So we send a message on the publisher site via

```
amqpTemplate.convertAndSend("exchange", "key", myEvent)
```

and expect to have `traceid` and `spanid` send along with the rabbit message and populated on the receiver/listener site, so it will be logged on the listener site too.

```
@RabbitHandler
public void on(MyEvent event) {
  LOGGER.warn("got a message...");
  ...
}
```

According to [this article](https://spring.io/blog/2016/02/15/distributed-tracing-with-spring-cloud-sleuth-and-spring-cloud-zipkin) I would expect this to work out of the box.

If I check the RabbitMQ messages directly (via trace), then I can see that the information is not available in the message, therefore its most probably the sender site having an issue...

One thing coming to my mind is, that we have configured a `Jackson2JsonMessageConverter` to allow json payloads:

```
@Bean
public Jackson2JsonMessageConverter jacksonConverter(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
    return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter(objectMapper);
}
```

btw. the log4j pattern is configured with the `%X` and prints the info if available:

```
<PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %X [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
```

what did I miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed the last piece of this sentence

> requests over messaging technologies like Apache Kafka or RabbitMQ (or any other Spring Cloud Stream binder

Sleuth doesn't work with `RabbitHandler`. In terms of messaging it works only with Spring Integration and Spring Cloud Stream.

Comment: sad, but thanks! - found this: https://github.com/netshoes/spring-cloud-sleuth-amqp-starter does not fullly work yet, but at least the info is now in the rabbit message. Need to check why it is still not propagated to the logs...